# Making a new view controller appear after interstitial ad is dismissed

Tags: swift, xcode, admob

I am building an iOS app in swift with Xcode that has a button that, when pressed, will (among other things) show an interstitial Admob ad, and then go to a different view controller. Right now, when I press the button, an interstitial ad will appear. However, when I close the ad, the view is still on the original page. If I click the button again, then I am taken to the second view controller. Sometimes, however, I have to dismiss three or four ads before I get to the second view controller. How can I make it so that, after I dismiss the interstitial ad, I go straight to the second view controller?

Here is the current code:

```
@IBAction func postPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        if contact.text?.isEmpty == true {
            print("No contact")
            return
        }
        if avail.text?.isEmpty == true {
            print("No availability")
            return
        }
        uploadSpot()
    }
    
    func uploadSpot() {
        let key = Int.random(in: 20001..<30000)
        let object: [String: Any] = [
            "Contact": contact.text!,
            "Availability": avail.text!,
        ]
        geoFireRef.child("\(key)").setValue(object)
        let location = manager.location!
        geoFire.setLocation(location, forKey: "\(key)")
        if interstitialAd?.isReady == true {
            interstitialAd?.present(fromRootViewController: self)
        }
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "SpotLoaded", bundle: nil)
            let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "SpotLoaded")
            vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
            present(vc, animated: true)
        
    }
```

The import part is in the function "uploadSpot()," where

```
if interstitialAd?.isReady == true {
            interstitialAd?.present(fromRootViewController: self)
        }
```

presents the ad and

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "SpotLoaded", bundle: nil)
            let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "SpotLoaded")
            vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
            present(vc, animated: true)
```

switches the viewcontroller. I have tried reversing the order if these two (i.e. putting `let storyboard`, etc., before `if insterstitialAd`), but that just takes me to the new view controller and the ad never appears. I have also tried putting the `let storyboard` chunk inside of the brackets following the `if interstitialAd`. This does not help either. If I put it after `interstitialAd?.present(fromRootViewController: self)`, I have the same problem where the ad shows but the view controller does not change. If I put it after, the viewcontroller changes but the ad never shows.

As the main purpose of interstitial ads is to appear in between views of an app, I do not think what I am trying to do should be so difficult. I think there must just be something I am missing or do not understand. Please help in whatever way you can.

Comment: Can you make the presenting VC be a *delegate* of the ad VC? That way you can have the ad VC *tell* the presenting VC that it is about to be dismissed, and then you navigate to the next VC.

Comment: Turns out I had already made an extension to make the VC a GADInterstitialDelegate. I cut out the ```let storyboard``` bit and just stuck it in the ```interstitionalDidDismiss``` function in the extension and now it works perfectly. Thanks!